# Merge three file in to a single master file by excluding the header in 2nd and 3rd files

Tags: text-processing, ksh, aix

I have three file with n number of lines as given below

sample1.txt

```
------------------------------
Date        Time    Name    
------------------------------
2013/10/12  12:09:09    Krish
2013/10/12  13:12:01    Ramb
2013/10/12  15:28:39    Likha
2013/10/12  15:56:12    Mat
.
.
.
```

Sample2.txt

```
------------------------------
Date        Time    Name    
------------------------------
2013/10/12  11:19:21    Jack
2013/10/12  12:11:09    Rob
2013/10/12  15:45:12    Rick
2013/10/12  22:11:10    Phil
.
.
.
```

Sample3.txt

```
------------------------------
Date        Time    Name    
------------------------------
2013/10/12  12:09:09    Eric
2013/10/12  13:12:01    Bob
2013/10/12  15:28:39    Mike
2013/10/12  15:56:12    Nick
.
.
.
```

I need to merge these three files in a single file(Master.txt) by excluding the headers (First 3 lines) in Sample2.txt and Sample3.txt
as given below

Desired Output

```
$cat Master.txt

------------------------------
Date        Time    Name    
------------------------------
2013/10/12  12:09:09    Krish
2013/10/12  13:12:01    Ramb
2013/10/12  15:28:39    Likha
2013/10/12  15:56:12    Mat
2013/10/12  11:19:21    Jack
2013/10/12  12:11:09    Rob
2013/10/12  15:45:12    Rick
2013/10/12  22:11:10    Phil
2013/10/12  12:09:09    Eric
2013/10/12  13:12:01    Bob
2013/10/12  15:28:39    Mike
2013/10/12  15:56:12    Nick
```

Note : In AIX machine with Ksh 88

Comment: This is probably best done programmatically. Possibly using Python and Perl. If you are doing such things frequently, you could consider using R. R will let you import the individual files as data frames, and then you can merge the data frames together. I believe Python's pandas for example offers similar functionality, but I have not used it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Perl/Python is certainly overkill for this. Plus Python on AIX might be slightly problematic.

Comment: @peterph Well, maybe. But if he has to do such manipulations frequently, then the R approach has much to recommend it. Though I have no idea about the current status of R on AIX. Though R of pretty much any vintage should able to do these kinds of manipulations.

Comment: @FaheemMitha why on earth would you recommend R for this? All the OP needs is to remove topmost 3 lines from all but the first file. Given UNIX strongly text-based interface it is work for the standard utilities.

Comment: @peterph Well, it is not necessary for this particular manipulation, but it seems the poster has need to manipulate text tables, and in general R is a good way to do so, and probably scales better to more complex situations. An alternative approach of using unix tools is certainly feasible. I'm not suggesting that is a bad way to go.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
{ cat sample1.txt; tail -n +4 sample2.txt; tail -n +4 sample3.txt; } > out.txt
```

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: Regrets for the earlier comment. Thanks it works perfectly as expected..!!!

Comment: @ram the `tail -n +4` means that, _regardless_ of the size of the file the top 3 lines are excluded.  I just tried it with a 10 line fie.  Don't mix up the "4" here with the fact that your sample has 4 lines.  That's basically a coincidence.

Comment: @ram :) for completeness, `head` has a similar option: `-n -X` will print **all but the last** `X` lines.

Comment: @peterph, not on AIX, not in the POSIX specification (only positive numbers allowed)

Comment: Hm, my bad... this is a GNU extension.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant & peterph : Thanks for the info...!

Comment: A reference to the use of curly braces for command grouping: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Answer (score 7):

```
sed '4,${/^---/d;/^Date/d;}' sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: +1 but could you add a bit of an explanation? What does the `${}` syntax do in `sed`?

Comment: That's not `${}`, but "do `{...}` on lines 4 to last"; it removes matching lines, but only after the first header has gone by. Using tail is more general and more robust, though.

Comment: @terdon as said, `{}` is grouping of commands.

Comment: @alexis depends on what you want in the end. One of the advantages (not that important these days though) is that it only spawns one process. Plus you can easily make it a script with `#!/bin/sed` being the interpreter.